# How to setup user login for only one table via phpmysql?

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to give somebody access via phpmyadmin to ONE table of one database ONLY with different user name and password?
If so, how do I set this up?

Comment: You can create a new user in your database (Operations tab). Do not `GRANT` them any right by default, and only give them `SELECT` (and potentially `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) rights on the one table.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. If you have any errors doing this, you might not have high enough privileges

Using phpmyadmin:

- Go to the Users tab for the Server
- Click 'Add user'.
- Don't grant any global privileges.
- After you save the user, from the Users overview table, click 'Edit Privileges' for your new user
- On the next page, don't grant anything. Scroll down and select the database you want
- On the next page, don't grant anything. Scroll down again and select the Table you want
- Finally, actually grant privileges for the Table and Columns.